# Why does my rotate animation lagg on some devices android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview

I have an imageview behind some buttons and on my HTC One X it works perfectly fine but on a HTC One it laggs and makes the app useless. It also works on my nexus 7 (new and old) and on an old asus tablet. all of them are on 4.4. I also recieved some playstore reviews mentioning the lagging on Galaxy S5, Xpreia Z1.

Any idea why that is?

Here ist the animation code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">

    <rotate
        android:duration="100000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite" />

</set>
```

And in my activity i simply call in the onCreate method

```
rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);
rotateview = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
rotateview.startAnimation(rotate);
```

Imageview xml:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/fog"
        android:layout_marginRight="-200dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-200dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-200dp"
        android:alpha="0.5" />
```

I also have an alternate version of the imageview which causes the same problem:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ring"
            android:alpha="0.5" />
```

Comment: updated it with the code

Comment: usually margin/padding causes lag....

Comment: ok but the second image view is lagging too

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` under `<application>` tag in your AndroidManifest.xml